# Expression Engine Advanced Search - Problems searching for keyword

Tags: php, html, search, expressionengine

I'm having a little trouble with expression engine searching! I've got a drop down form set-up that works great, however I need to add an OPTIONAL keyword field into this search form. Any ideas how i'll do this with my current code:

Main form code:

```
<form method="post" action="/properties/search-results/">

            <p>Keywords:</p>
            <input id="keywords" type="text" name="keywords"/>

            <p>Town:</p>
            <select id="town" name="cat[]" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Any</option>
                {exp:channel:categories channel="property" style="linear" category_group="1"}
                <option value="{category_id}">{category_name}</option>
                {/exp:channel:categories}
            </select>

            <p>Property Type:</p>
            <select id="propertyType" name="cat[]">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Any</option>
                {exp:channel:categories channel="property" style="linear" category_group="2"}
                <option value="{category_id}">{category_name}</option>
                {/exp:channel:categories}
            </select>

            <input style="margin-top:20px; width: 100px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>
```

Search-results template:

```
<?php
// Grab the categories selected from the $_POST
// join them with an ampersand - we are searching for AND matches
$cats = "";
foreach($_POST['cat'] as $cat){
// check we are working with a number
if(is_numeric($cat)){
$cats .= $cat."&";
}
}
// strip the last & off the category string
$cats = substr($cats,0,-1);
?>

{exp:channel:entries channel="property" dynamic="on" category="<?php echo($cats);?>" orderby="date" sort="asc"}
```

I need the keyword field to search in the {title} of my entries!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: first install the [Search Fields](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/search-fields) plugin. (You need this because the native EE `"search:field_name"` parameter only works on custom fields, not entry titles.)

Then use this revised code:

```
<?php
// Grab the categories selected from the $_POST
// join them with an ampersand - we are searching for AND matches
$cats = array();
foreach($_POST['cat'] as $cat)
{
    // check we are working with a number
    if(is_numeric($cat))
    {
        $cats[] = $cat;
    }
}
$cats = implode('&', $cats);

if(!empty($_POST['keywords']))
{
    $keywords = trim($_POST['keywords']);
}
?>

<?php if($keywords) : ?>
{exp:search_fields search:title="<?php echo($keywords);?>" channel="property" parse="inward"}
<?php endif; ?>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="property" <?php if($keywords) : ?>entry_id="{search_results}"<?php endif; ?> category="<?php echo($cats);?>" orderby="date" sort="asc"}
        {!-- do stuff --}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
<?php if($keywords) : ?>
{/exp:search_fields}
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Derek, Thanks alot for this however i'm having a little issue with it. It doesn't report any errors or anything but when I submit the search form, it just brings up a blank page?

Comment: Hi Derek, I changed the PHP parsing to output and it's now bringing me an expression engine template page stating "Search must be 3 characters in length" even though I am searching for more than 3 characters.

Comment: PHP should definitely be on input. Set debug to 1 in your index.php file to see what errors might be coming up.

Comment: Hi Derek, Now getting the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/inc_marketing/campbellcairns.com/admin/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(656) : eval()'d code on line 11

Comment: Ops, I had a missing semicolon in there. It should  be `$cats[] = $cat;`. Try fixing that and see what happens.

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks very much, I noticed that myself and got it working great BUT a little issue now...  I need the keywords box to be optional? So if the user just selects a town and a property type and leaves the keywords blank, it will still search?

Comment: I just added a conditional statement to the code, let me know if the works.

Comment: Hi Derek, seems to work great but i'm getting 2 errors: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: cat

Filename: libraries/Functions.php(656) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 5

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: libraries/Functions.php(656) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 5